# How to add an <a href> link to <div> and inline styling

Tags: html, css, inline, divider

**Here is the url for the home page:**  http://www.auvsishow.org/auvsi2015/public/mainhall.aspx

**Here is the current markup for the "Attendee" Button.**

Thanks all.

Comment: instead of the 'div' just make it an 'a'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for doing this is putting div tag inside a tag.

```
<a href="Content.aspx?ID=1526">   
    <div id="home_travel_btn">
    </div>        
</a>

#home_travel_btn {
    width: 437px; 
    height: 128px; 
    float: left; 
    background-image: url(http://www.auvsishow.org/auvsi2015/custom/images/interface/Travel_btn_sprite.png);
}
```

Check example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/4j4wyukz/